Does setting the parking brake while airborne affects drag?
If you're flying a fixed gear airplane and set the parking brakes while cruising, will this cause an increase or decrease in the drag? Or will this have any other effect on the aircraft?
UPDATE:
After doing more detailed research and watching many GoPro footage people post online from various fixed gear airplanes in all flight phases(takeoff, cruise, landing) I realized that the gears do not spin during cruise on the first place(as mentioned by @abelenky on personal observation)
It seems as if the air speed/friction with the gears is not strong enough to make them spin to start with.
And thinking about it I think it will be very hard to find an airplane where this occurs, since the drag of having fixed gears wont allow it to fly that fast, hence the invention of retractable landing gear airplanes.
Which brings me to this question: What is the fastest fixed gear airplane?
We might be able to find footage of such airplane and see if the phenomena occurs.

One might imagine that a gear wheel with a cowling over the top might be spun up by drag. My intuition says that once fully spun up (with axel friction balancing the drag moment) the overall drag on the vehicle would marginally decrease because the relative velocity would be lower. On the other hand, my intuition also recognizes some analogy between the wheel and a ram air turbine. You could extract work from the spinning wheel, which makes me feel like there could be some energy argument for an increase in required thrust (or more drag). Very interesting question.

From direct, personal observation in a C-172: My main gear does not spin in flight, so setting the parking brake would not change anything. I do not know if this would apply to all aircraft.
The ENORMOUS safety risk is that you could land with the parking brake set, which would be immediately disastrous. No possible fuel savings is worth that risk.

Yes, I'm aware of the risks of doing something like this, the question is only about aerodynamics/physics.

@Gabe You could ask on the Physics, but you will have to explain what parking break is, how it works etc.

Out of curiostity, are GA aircraft tested/certified for this kind of condition (landing with brake set, tire blowing up and consequences?)

@Dimitar, do you really think the people on Physics SE don't know what a parking brake is, or is that a dig?

@MichaelHall, if you don't specify this sort of thing, you'll get answers that only apply to a spherical airplane in a vacuum.

@Mark, you have a point there... ;)

@MichaelHall You can't expect people to know everything about everything.

@Dimitar, right... but if someone is smart enough to answer such a question there's a non-zero chance that they own a car.

If the landing gear is not inside of the aircraft during flight, and the wheels pick up speed (start spinning), then activating the brakes on the wheels will decrease rotational drag caused by the spinning wheels.
On the other hand, if you have your wheels extended, that by itself will drastically increase drag, they really should be tucked into the aircraft for optimal drag performance. Stopping them from spinning is like picking up an elephant with a toothpick compared to the drag caused by the extended wheels.

The question specified "a fixed gear airplane", so retracting the gear isn't an option.
